# Вписывание переменных в запрос MySQL - в чём разница?

Tags: php, mysql

Вот 3 запроса, по первым двум сразу скажу: 2-ой у меня работает, а вот первый, который всегда советуют - нет. Вопрос вообще в том, в чём ключевая разница этих вписаний переменных в запрос?

```
$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field=".$A." WHERE $table.field2=".$B."", $db);                
$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field='$A' WHERE $stable.field2='$B'", $db);               
$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field=$A WHERE $table.field2=$B", $db);
```

Чем ".$A." отличается от '$A'?

С последним, где просто $A понятно, там если переменная стринговая, то может прийти пробел.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у тебя поле `$table.field` имеет строковый тип, то значение должно быть в одинарных кавычках, т.е. `$table.field = 'сообщение'`, если напишешь `$table.field = сообщение`  - будет ошибка.

Двойные кавычки - это в данном случае считай инструкция `php` (обрамляет строку), а одинарные - это часть `sql` запроса (обрамляет значение переменной).

А вот первый и третий вариант ничем друг от друга не отличаются, читай работу со строками в php.